# ORA-00936: missing expression Java SQL Exception

Tags: sql, oracle

I´ve been trying to find the error in this statement for a few hours and can´t seem to find it.

It must have something to do with the AND connecting the two WHERE´s since when deleting the first WHERE it works:

```
SELECT  E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.FIBU_FIRMA, 
        E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.AUFTR_NR, 
        E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.KOMMENTAR, 
        AUFTR_EXT.ART_GRUPPE 
        FROM HHNG_AU.E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE 
        INNER JOIN HHNG_AU.AUFTR_EXT ON E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.AUFTR_NR = AUFTR_EXT.AUFTR_NR 
        WHERE (E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.AUFTR_NR = '1248823' ) 
        AND WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM HHNG_AU.EX_KOMMENTARE WHERE EX_KOMMENTARE.AUFTR_NR = '1248823' )
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with java. seeing as we don't know what it is you are trying to do, guessing is about as much as we can do

Comment: `AND WHERE` should be `AND `. You can only have **one** `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This was beginning to drive me nuts.

Comment: Why on earth does this get 4 downvotes?! I posted the error I received and described what the Problem is (I couldn´t get the SQL Statement to work) @ 4 Downvoters: Shall I write a 5 page Essay about it you stupid morons or whats your Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Too many `WHERE`. You only need where once, then use `AND`s and `OR`s to combine conditions:

`SELECT E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.FIBU_FIRMA, E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.AUFTR_NR, E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.KOMMENTAR, AUFTR_EXT.ART_GRUPPE FROM HHNG_AU.E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE INNER JOIN HHNG_AU.AUFTR_EXT ON E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.AUFTR_NR = AUFTR_EXT.AUFTR_NR WHERE (E_AUFMASS_KOMMENTARE.AUFTR_NR = '1248823' ) AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM HHNG_AU.EX_KOMMENTARE WHERE EX_KOMMENTARE.AUFTR_NR = '1248823' )`